# How to create release channels with electron/electron-builder?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have an [Electron](http://electron.atom.io) app where I want to introduce parallel release channels: `stable`, `next` (for early adopters) and `dev` (for testing the latest build).

These will have a branch each, with new features appearing first in `dev`, progressing to `next` for beta testing and finally moving into `stable`.

I'm using [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) to make these release packages, and I want each to have its own auto-updates - so when I publish a new `next` release all the users with it get the update.

I want the applications to be independent - a user can have two channels installed and run both at the same time. They'll have different names and different icons.

I can manually set these up in the branches, but really I want to automate this as much as possible - a publish from the `next` branch should use the right name, icons, IDs and updater without risk of it going to the wrong channel.

Is there a way to do this with electron or electron-builder?

Answer (score 10):

It's possible with `electron-builder`. I would have several build configurations and tell `electron-builder` which to use when building.

For example, create file `config/beta.json` with the following setup:

```
{
  "appId": "com.company.beta",
  "productName": "App Beta",
  "directories": {
    "buildResources": "build/beta" // directory containing your build-specific assets (e.g., beta icons - icon.icns, icon.ico & background.png)
  },
  "mac": {
    "category": "public.app-category.finance"
  },
  "win": {
    "target": [
      "nsis"
    ]
  },
  "nsis": {
    "perMachine": false
  },
  "publish": [
    {
      "provider": "s3",
      "bucket": "com-app-beta" // dedicated S3 bucket for each build
    }
  ],
}
```

And duplicate `config/beta.json` for `next.json` and `current.json` (make sure to edit settings accordingly).

In `package.json`, add the following build scripts (note `--em.name=app-beta` to overwrite `package.json`'s "name" value):

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "build -owl --x64 --config ./config/current.json -p always --em.name=app",
        "build-beta": "build -owl --x64 --config ./config/beta.json -p always --em.name=app-beta",
        "build-next": "build -owl --x64 --config ./config/next.json -p always --em.name=app-next"
    }
}
```

Run build script when ready to deploy:

```
npm run build-beta
```

Answer (score 3):

Using electron-builder version 20.15.1 and MacOS, @Jon Saw's solution needs a minor change because em option is not valid:

```
"build-beta": "build -owl --x64 --config ./config/beta.json -p always -c.extraMetadata.name=app-beta"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback and welcome to SO. This would be better as a comment on Jon Saw's answer, as that way they'll get a notification.

Answer (score 0):

electron-builder(latest: v24.9.1) provides us with [a way to distribute a pre-release version](https://www.electron.build/tutorials/release-using-channels).

Three release channels are available: "latest", "beta" and "alpha." The default is "latest".

So, you can use "latest" as "stable", "beta" as "next", "alpha" as "dev".

It's simple to use it. If we want to build a beta version app, we add "-beta" to the version name in `package.json`.

```json
"name": "my-electron-app",
"version": "1.2.3-beta",
```

After this change in `package.json`, the electron-builder outputs `beta.yml` instead of `latest.yml` when building. Of course, the file name of the built application is also changed to `1.2.3-beta`.